# How to create a NestJs Pipe with a config object and dependency?

Tags: nestjs

I would Like to pass a configuration string to a Pipe but also want to inject a service.  The NesJs docs describe how to do both of these independent of each other but not together.   Take the following example:

pipe.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class FileExistsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private filePath: string, db: DatabaseService) { }

  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const path = value[this.filePath];
    const doesExist =  await this.db.file(path).exists()
    if(!doesExist)  throw new BadRequestException();
    return value;
  }
}
```

controller.ts

```js
@Controller('transcode')
export class TranscodeController {

  @Post()
  async transcode ( 
    @Body( new FileExistsPipe('input')) transcodeRequest: JobRequest) {
    return await this.videoProducer.addJob(transcodeRequest);
  }
```

Basically, I want to be able to pass a property name to my pipe (e.g.`'input'`) and then have the pipe look up the value of the property in the request (e.g.`const path = value[this.filePath]`) and then look to see if the file exists or not in the database.  If it doesn't, throw a Bad Request error, otherwise continue.

The issue I am facing is that I need NestJs to inject my DataBaseService.  With the current example, It won't and my IDE gives me an error that `new FileExistsPipe('input')` only has one argument passed but was expecting two (e.g. DatabaseService).

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: I just checked your repo (sorry for missing it before). Your `DatabaseService` is `undefined` in the `FIleExistPipe` because you use the pipe in `AppController`. `AppController` will be resolved before the `DatabaseModule` gets resolved. You can use `forwardRef()` to inject the `DatabaseService` in your pipe if you are going to use the pipe in `AppController`. The good practice here is to have feature controllers provided in feature modules.

```js
export const FileExistPipe: (filePath: string) => PipeTransform = memoize(
  createFileExistPipe
);

function createFileExistPipe(filePath: string): Type<PipeTransform> {
  class MixinFileExistPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(
      // use forwardRef here
      @Inject(forwardRef(() => DatabaseService)) private db: DatabaseService 
    ) {
      console.log(db);
    }

    async transform(value: ITranscodeRequest, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
      console.log(filePath, this.db);
      const doesExist = await this.db.checkFileExists(filePath);
      if (!doesExist) throw new BadRequestException();
      return value;
    }
  }

  return mixin(MixinFileExistPipe);
}
```

---

You can achieve this with `Mixin`. Instead of exporting an `injectable` class, you'd export a factory function that would return such class.

```js
export const FileExistPipe: (filePath: string) => PipeTransform = memoize(createFileExistPipe);

function createFileExistPipe(filePath: string) {
    class MixinFileExistPipe implements PipeTransform {
        constructor(private db: DatabaseService) {}
        ...
    }

    return mixin(MixinFileExistPipe);
}
```

1. `memoize` is just a simple function to cache the created mixin-pipe with the `filePath`. So for each `filePath`, you'd only have a single version of that pipe.
2. `mixin` is a helper function imported from `nestjs/common` which will wrap the `MixinFileExistPipe` class and make the DI container available (so `DatabaseService` can be injected).

Usage:

```js
@Controller('transcode')
export class TranscodeController {

@Post()
async transcode (
    // notice, there's no "new"
    @Body(FileExistsPipe('input')) transcodeRequest: JobRequest) {
    return await this.videoProducer.addJob(transcodeRequest);
}
```

1. a mixin guard injecting the MongoDB Connection
   [image: a mixin guard injecting the MongoDB Connection]
2. the console shows the connection being logged
   [image: the console shows the connection being logged]

Comment: This solution doesn't work because it does not inject the DatabaseService.

Comment: @tommyc38 you'd probably need to provide some repro here because it works for me. Check updated answer for screenshot

Comment: Updated answer to include forwardRef